# How to decide whether the given value is float or double in Java?

Tags: java

What is the data type for the number `9.6352` in Java?

Actually if I postfix the number with 'd' or 'f'. then it will be quite easy to decide.
But if I leave it as alone, then which will be the default type of the number in java?

Comment: And one more thing Double is class while double is dataype. am i right?

Comment: `Double` is a class indeed, `double` is a [primitive type](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go check out the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) section on floating point literals (§3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d.

So it's a double if it's not suffixed.

Answer (score 8):

By default, any floating point data type without 'f' or 'F' postfixed, is considered as of type `double`.
Since the given number doesn't end with 'f'/'F', it is of type `double`.

We can optionally add 'd' or 'D' at the end to mark it as a `double` type, but again, it is optional.

Answer (score 2):

For you interest;

- `0xD` is 13, `0xF` is 15
- `0D` is `(double) 0` and `0F` is `(float) 0`.

Answer (score 1):

By default it's `double` primitive type.