# How to parse an integer, when I have a format for a double?

Tags: java, types

I'm taking user entries from my database, which stores the values user entered that might be either float or int, but my code meant to check the following condition

```
String pattern = "###,###.##";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
if (!userput.equals("")){
        resultoutput.setText(""+Double.parseDouble(userput)*Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(x[1]))));}
        else{
            userinput.setText("1");
            resultoutput.setText(""+Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(x[1]))));
        }
```

So when it encounters `int` it crashes. For example, for 13152  it gives `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "13,152"`

Moreover if i get the output as something like this `13170.00` i get the error as follows `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "13,170.00"`

Sometimes the values fetched from the database contains float and sometimes integer, here `x[1]` is the currency exchange rate and `userinput` contains `integer` or `float`....lets say i am trying to get `usd to idr` `currency` so i get `13170.00` which is not `double` neither `int` because i get this error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "13,170.00"`

Comment: it'd be float, since integers (of ANY size) cannot store decimal places.

Comment: If you are talking about a constant represented by a Java literal, as in `<some-type> d = 13143.98`, then its type is `double`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231459/how-to-decide-whether-the-given-value-is-float-or-double-in-java/8231497#8231497

Comment: For the question at the end - do you mean how to convert `String` to `double`?

Comment: "Update 2" is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-double-java

Comment: sorry sir but that's not the same, the problem i am facing is i need double but if i get integer what should i do

Comment: Now that we have the real question, can you please add what the `userput` and `x` variables contain? What do they contain in a good case? What do they contain in a bad case?

Comment: sir, i'm making a currency converter app so sometimes the values fetched from the database contains float and sometimes integer, here `x[1]` is the currency exchange rate and `userinput` contains integer or float....lets say i am trying to get `usd to idr` currency so i get `13170.00` which is not `double` neither `int`

Comment: If you work on currencies, then avoid `double`s at all. Please read about `BigDecimal`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359817/using-bigdecimal-to-work-with-currencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in whether the number is integer or double. Your problem lies in the fact that your conversion rate has more than three digits.

This is your code for displaying the value (reformatted):

```
resultoutput.setText(
    ""
    + Double.parseDouble(userput)
    * Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(x[1]))));
```

So, you are:

1. Taking your exchange rate, which is a string, and converting it to double.
2. Taking the resulting double, and converting it back to string, using a decimal format.
3. Taking that formatted text, and converting it again to double
4. Multiplying it by the double value of the user input
5. Converting the result to a string (without formatting).

The problem lies in step 2 and 3. They are actually unnecessary. But for some numbers they will work.

Your format is `###,###.##`. Let's see how some numbers look when they are formatted with this format:

```
╔═════════╤═══════════╗
║ number  │ formatted ║
╠═════════╪═══════════╣
║ 0.273   │ 0.27      ║
╟─────────┼───────────╢
║ 5.3     │ 5.3       ║
╟─────────┼───────────╢
║ 358.2   │ 358.2     ║
╟─────────┼───────────╢
║ 10.0    │ 10        ║
╟─────────┼───────────╢
║ 1298.52 │ 1,298.52  ║
╚═════════╧═══════════╝
```

So, when you have conversion rates that are smaller than four digits to the left of the decimal point, the `decimalFormat.format()` call converts them to a string that is still a legal Java double. So when you then call `Double.parseDouble` on this string in step 3, everything is good.

But when you have a large number, such as `"13152.00"`, what you do is:

1. Convert it into double: `13152.0`
2. Convert it into string with a format: `13,152.0`
3. Convert it into double: - this doesn't work. Java is not accepting `,` in the input for `Double.parseDouble()`.

So really, your conversion should just be:

```
resultoutput.setText(
    ""
    + Double.parseDouble(userput)
    * Double.parseDouble(x[1]));
```

This will give you a proper, unformatted number in your `resultoutput`, without throwing your an exception.

I'm pretty sure you intended the `decimalFormat` in order to display the number, not in order to convert it again and again. This means you should only use it on the result of the conversion - instead of doing `"" + ...`, which gives you just default formatting.

```
resultoutput.setText(
    decimalFormat.format( Double.parseDouble(userput) * Double.parseDouble(x[1])));
```

Be warned, though, that you will not see two digits after the decimal point with your format - it will display `10.0` as `10`. If you want to always display two digits, you have to use `###,##0.00` as your format.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping out with everything

Answer (score 1):

It's `double`, because it contains `.` and doesn't contain `f` or `F` suffix.

From [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> The floating point types (float and double) can also be expressed
>   using E or e (for scientific notation), F or f (32-bit float literal)
>   and D or d (**64-bit double literal; this is the default and by
>   convention is omitted**).

```
double d1 = 123.4;
// same value as d1, but in scientific notation
double d2 = 1.234e2;
float f1  = 123.4f;
```

Comment: Float and Long also contain a dot.

Comment: There is no `f` at the end of it, it is a double.

Comment: My comment was before his edit, which only said that it's a double because it contains a dot.

Comment: None of them "contact" a dot. And saying long was a mistake, I realize the error now. But Float **does** contain a "dot" you can say `1.32F` and it's still a float.... with a dot..